# Highlight current page navigation item

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a floating page navigation list on my site. It has all the headers of the page, and the user can comfortably click the page navigation items to go to the correct anchor of the page. It also helps greatly in letting the visitor understand page structure, and to know where on the page he/she is.

Now, to help the user understand where on the page he/she is, I'd like for the correct item in the page navigation list to get highlighted (adding/removing CSS classes) depending on where the user is.

I hope I have explained myself well. How is this done? Thanks!

**- EDIT -**

Thanks Talgat for your answer. I now have this code:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
```

This is my controller:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("validateCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.isActive = {};
    $scope.isActive = function (state) {
        return state === $state.current.name;
    };
});
</script>
```

This is a anchor link from the navigation list to one of the tours we offer called "Ancestral Adventure":

```
<a href="#ancestral-adventure" ng-class="{active: isActive('ancestral-adventure')}">Ancestral Adventure</a>
```

"ancestral-adventure" is the id of a header. Perhaps I should wrap the "Ancestral Adventure"-content in a div instead with this id, though? This is the header:

```
<h3 id="ancestral-adventure" name="ancestral-adventure">Ancestral Adventure</h3>
```

As your angular code mentioned `name` in `$state.current.name`, I added a name and ng-name with same value to the header as well, just to be safe.

With this code, the navigation list items are not updated - nothing happens. I have made sure the `active` class works for the list items, and that the AngularJS library is working. What might I be doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Does a click cause the hash portion (or fragment portion, the part after `#`) in the URL to be updated? Then you can use [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:target) (in combination with `animation`).

Comment: Or do you want only the item in the navigation list to be highlighted instead of the actual section on the page?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Xufox. Yes, I wanted the navigation list item to be highlighted - not the section in the page content itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$state` service to check is current navigation item is active or not. Here some example to realize that. Add following code to your controller:

```
$scope.isActive = function (state) {
  return state === $state.current.name;
};
```

and add this in templete:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li ng-class="{active: isActive('route-name')}">
  </li>
</ul>
```

The `active: isActive('route-name')` will assign `active` class to the `li` tag if current item is active, then you can highlight that item with css.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Talgat! This is a great opportunity for me to continue learning AngularJS. I've just started learning this, so I'm a real novice. I've updated by question with my current code.

Answer (score 0):

So from what i understand you want to create sth like bootstrap [ScrollSpy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy)
It requires calculating vertical scroll position against header element positions.
You can try and use one of scroll spy implementations for angular.
Two first results from google:

- [ngScrollSpy](http://mg.github.io/ngScrollSpy/)
- [angular-scroll](http://oblador.github.io/angular-scroll/)